# Why Rails hides the existence of id column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't quite understand the need to hide the existence of `id` column in Rails.
It is neither reflected in `migration` file nor the `schema.rb` file.
There is no way for a newbie to know for the fact that a column named `id` has been created by default as a `primary key`.
Unless they go and check the actual schema of the table in database (`rails dbconsole`).

I can see the `timestamps` macro included by default in the migration file as well as in `schema.rb` as two fields `created_at` and `updated_at`. Here, a developer at least gets a clue. Rails could have done the same for `id` column too. But it doesn't.

Why the secrecy around `id` column? Is it a part of the famous `convention over configuration`? Or is it a norm across all MVC frameworks?

Comment: It's the Rails team's choice to do so.

Comment: @wurde but the `choice` also comes with a flexibility of resetting the `id: false` too....

Comment: Ok. You can set id to false. Be sure to keep normalized data or risk integrity of your records.

Comment: self.primary_key = "isbn"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In database design it is generally accepted that numeric id's are preferred, because

- they are easier to index, and thus easier to "follow" or check when creating links (foreign keys).
- when editing/updating records, you have a unique (and efficient) identifier

So therefore it is advised to give all tables a unique numeric key, always.

Now this numeric key has no meaning whatsoever to your application, it is a "implementation detail" of your database layer. Also to make sure every table has an id, unless you explicitly ask not to.

I think this would indeed fall under the "convention over configuration" nomer: why explicitly specify an id for each table if you each table should have one.

The timestamps is different: this is interesting for some tables, but for same tables it is not important at all. It also depends on your application.

Note that this is not at all related to MVC. The M in MVC is a container for data, but in MVC it is actually not really important how the Model gets filled. In other words: the ORM part is not part of MVC. You will see that in most MVC implementations there is no ORM, or definitely not as tightly integrated as with Rails.

So in short: imho ommitting the 'id' from the migration is not a secret, it is just to make life easier, saves you some more typing, *and* it makes sure you follow a good convention unless you explicitly do *not* want to.

Comment: Thanks. :) That's a pretty good explanation matches to somewhere down the line I was thinking.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably due to the fact that relational databases tend to use integer primary keys, and doing otherwise introduces complexities. I guess the reason it's hidden in rails is so that creating tables with integer primary keys does not require any special configuration, and having to write it into rails migrations invites inexperienced developers to play around with it (which is probable not a good idea).

Additionally, I think rails tries to abstract away things like numeric ids, if you want to create associations in a migration you do not need to specify foreign keys, you can simply write the name of the object you want to relate the table to.

Answer (score 0):

I never thinked about the id field because almost every table have an id....

Check the documentation about [migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) where they say:

> A primary key column called id will also be added implicitly, as it's
>   the default primary key for all Active Record models. The timestamps
>   macro adds two columns, created_at and updated_at. These special
>   columns are automatically managed by Active Record if they exist.

If you want to check your table columns, just go to rails console and type `Model.column_names`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's clear that if you don't add a primary key, then rails will add one generic key for you so that it can index your record and have a control over it, so basically it isn't stating that there WILL be an ID field, since I don't believe this has to be imperative, but rather optional in the event you do not provide a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Rails convention to hide the I'd attribute to discourage and remove temptation of playing with it.

id attr is automatically generated with auto_increment to ad normalization to your data(to make each record unique an accessible). Injecting your own values would eventually corrupt and break the magic of ActiveRecord.